# Set wireframe only view

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

[In this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e16c8uaCwzY&t=10m0s), the author says to set the view to wireframe at 10:08.

In blender 2.7, the menu looks slightly different. When I set to 'wireframe' I do not see the same results.

[image]

How can I accomplish what the author is trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That panel was shuffled around a bit since the tutorial was made. The option you want is now called *Maximum draw type*:

[image]

Also make sure *Optimal display* is enabled on the subsurf modifier.

Comment: Optimal Display was my problem. Also I had to make sure the object was selected first. Thanks